# Cubic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

I have a solution to a differential equation $y^3/3+2y^2+4y = t + k$. I want it in the form $y = f(t)$. Wolfram alpha tells me the answer is $y = \sqrt[3]{k - 3t -8} - 2 $. Now how did it do that?

Comment: It is odd since the equation can be written as  $$(y+2)^3=3t+3k+8$$

Comment: Why the tag ''differential-equation'' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying your equation by $3$ it becomes:
$$
y^3+6y^2+12y=3t+3k
$$
completing the cube at LHS we have:
$$
y^3+6y^2+12y+8=(y+2)^3=3t+3k+8
$$

so:

$$
y=\sqrt[3]{3t+3k+8}-2
$$

Note that [Wolfram-alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E3%2F3%20%2B2y%5E2%20%2B%204y%20%3D%20t%2Bk) gives all the three solution in $\mathbb{C}$ and the real solution is write as

$$
y=-\sqrt[3]{-3t-3k-8}-2
$$

(you have some typos with the minus signs in your question)